# FB.Event.comment.create event does not fire with initial comment(s)

Tags: facebook, comments

I'm trying to capture the `comment.create` event but notice that it does not fire when the `iframe` is loaded initially with no comments. If there were existing comments, the events (both `comment.create` and `comment.remove`) will fire but they don't fire when there are no initial comments.

Is there a solution for this?

**Update 1**: for clarification: When the `iframe` is initially loaded without any comments and I post the first (or subsequent comments) the `comment.create` event does not fire. If the `iframe` was loaded which already has one or more comments, the `comment.create` *will* fire when I submit a comment.

**Update 2**: Here's the bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19827

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it wrong, please read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) again:

> **comment.create** - fired when the user adds a comment (fb:comments).

And:

> **comment.remove** - fired when the user removes a comment (fb:comments).

These events **don't** fire on page (iframe) load!

Comment: see my clarification. if the `iframe` was loaded without any comments the `comment.create` does not fire when I comment.

Comment: ah! now that's odd! I would wait for a day or two and if no answer solved your issue then report this as a bug!